# Rails 3 isn't loading gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails doesn't seem to be loading the Kaminari gem, as I get an `Uninitialized constant` error when starting up the development server:

```
/home/my_app/config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Kaminari (NameError)
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/my_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

However, I'm including it on the Gemfile, and running `gem list` shows that it is installed, as well. Any ideas? How can I track down this `Uninitialized constant` error?

Thanks!

My Gemfile:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'blueprint-rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'kaminari'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8' 
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano'  
end
```

My `gem list`

```
$ gem list
actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
arel (3.0.0)
blueprint-rails (0.1.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.22 ruby, 1.0.21)
capistrano (2.12.0)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
highline (1.6.12)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.1)
jquery-rails (2.0.0)
jruby-jars (1.6.7)
jruby-rack (1.1.4)
json (1.6.5)
kaminari (0.13.0)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.3.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
passenger (3.0.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
rvm-capistrano (1.1.0)
sass (3.1.14)
sass-rails (3.2.4)
sprockets (2.1.2)
therubyracer (0.10.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you're [using RVM to manage different ruby versions and different gemsets](https://rvm.io/) (sets of gems specific to each application). That's great.

But you're running the `gem` command outside rvm -- meaning it's not necessarily showing what rvm has set up for the specific ruby version you're using. It may also be that kaminari is on your machine, but not in the bundle for that application yet.

It may simply be that you've switched RVM rubies and not run bundle.

Can you run `bundle install` from your project root and verify that Kaminari is installed for that project's bundle?

Comment: Hi Kevin, per your suggestion, I ran `rvm 1.9.2-p290 do gem list`, and kaminari is shown there. Also, running `bundle install` shows it installed as well

Comment: Can you run `bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: No, it throws the same error `uninitialized constant Kaminari (NameError)`

Comment: This is weird. It should be there. Please try these steps in case you have a corrupted bundle -- they don't take long: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/ISSUES.md

Comment: It didn't work either... had my hopes up with this one :-(! Well, I'm going to try to rollback some code changes to check if that helps! thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Good luck! If I helped you out an upvote would be appreciated! Post back if it's something obvious. -kevin